# Gson with dynamic objects

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How to create following json object using Gson.

```
{
    "Locations":{
       "111": 123123,
       "112": 312312,
       "113": 576756,
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

I hope you may noticed that `Locations` has multiple dynamic objects. If its array then its very easy to create. So I am wonder is there any possible way to create this JSON object using gson.

Comment: in GSON  `"111": 123123` translates into `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: Which is the object you want to serialize into JSON?